# Converting an SQL query to a LINQ query with a complicated LEFT JOIN

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

The system I am using has two tables in it Employees table and a TimesheetHeader table.  The TimesheetHeader table has as a Foreign key the primary key of the employees table.  The query in SQL works just fine but I need it to be a LINQ query that C#.net will recognize.

```
SELECT e.Employee, e.Name, t.Status FROM Employees e LEFT JOIN TimesheetHeader t ON
e.Employee=t.EmployeeID WHERE e.unionID='CUPE 859' AND e.LabourClass='5' AND
e.Active=1 AND e.RoleID>=3 AND (t.TimesheetDate='02/09/2011' OR ISNULL(t.TimesheetDate,'')='')
```

ANY help here would be very much liked.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
DateTime someDate = new DateTime(2011, 09, 02)

from e in db.Employees
join th in db.TimeHeaders.Where(t => t.TimesheetDate == null || t.TimeSheetDate == someDate) 
into TimeSheetHeaders
where e.unionID = '' && e.LabourClass == '5' && (other conditions go here)
select new {Employee = e, TimeSheetHeaders}
```